# How to put big size button next to small size buttons?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make basic calculator.

But I am having a problem on styling.

I want my Clear button big and to be placed like this:

```
+---+---+---+---+-+
|BTN|BTN|BTN|BTN|C|
+---+---+---+---|L|
|BTN|BTN|BTN|BTN|E|
+---+---+---+---|A|
|BTN|BTN|BTN|BTN|R|
+---+---+---+---|B|
|BTN|BTN|BTN|BTN|T|
+---+---+---+---|N|
|BTN|BTN|BTN|BTN|!|
+---------------+-+
```

Seems easy work but already tried for an hour.

How can I style this?

Here is my html:

```html
 <div class="buttons">
      <div class="btnLine">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
      </div>
      <div class="btnLine">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
      </div>
      <div class="btnLine">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
      </div>
      <div class="btnLine">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
      </div>
      <div class="btnLine">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
      </div>
      <div class="btnLine">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
        <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: <input style="height:200px" value="Clear"/>

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
.buttons {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
.btnLine input.button {
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0 5px 10px 0;
}
.big-btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:10px;
}
.big-btn input.button {
    height: 230px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
   <div class="buttons">
  <div class="btnLine">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
  </div>
  <div class="btnLine">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
  </div>
  <div class="btnLine">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
  </div>
  <div class="btnLine">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
  </div>
  <div class="btnLine">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
  </div>
  <div class="btnLine">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
    <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="big-btn">
<input class="button" type="button" value="Clear">
</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

I have added height and margin  to each button.

Comment: Thank you. key was "float".

Comment: @zxxzyyz. `float` here is irrelevant and may cause a lot of bugs and lead to unintentional behavior. There is a great property `flex` introduced a while ago for such things. [Check that guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Answer (score 0):

Use Flex box:

```css
.calculator {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
}
.buttons {
    display: flex;

}
.btnLine input.button {
    display: flex;
}
.clear {  
   border: 1px solid grey; /*rewriting standard style, it is necessary to be able to change the size*/
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
    <div class="calculator">
        <div class="buttons">
            <div class="btnLine">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
            </div>
            <div class="btnLine">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
            </div>
            <div class="btnLine">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
            </div>
            <div class="btnLine">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
            </div>
            <div class="btnLine">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
            </div>
            <div class="btnLine">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
                <input class="button" type="button" value="BIN">
            </div>
        </div>
        <input class="clear" type="button" value="Clear">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```